# Yootheme WidgetKit for my CMS

Tags: jquery, cakephp, content-management-system

I created my own CMS with the framework CakePHP

I want to install the Yootheme WidgetKit Plugin but I don't know how to do it :

http://www.yootheme.com/widgetkit/

Can you help me please ?

If it's not possible, i would like to find a jquery plugin who work likes the SlideSet Deck here :
http://www.yootheme.com/widgetkit/examples/slideset

Thank you in advance.

Ilan

Answer (score 0):

Widgetkit is only compatible with Wordpress and Joomla CMS.

You should be able to use jcycle to achieve the same functionality
(http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/)

Good luck
Dave